# How to tell if user control is done loading in vb6

Tags: vb6

How can you tell if a VB6 user control is done loading? Is there a custom `UserControl_Loaded` event or something?

Answer (score 1):

What do you mean by loading? A UserControl has an Initialize event which you should use to set initial values. VB itself will then load in property values. In any of the other events you can assume the control is set up and ready to go.

You can read about the order of events a UserControl goes through here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa242140%28v=vs.60%29.aspx

Comment: What I meant was, what event will trigger after it is being initialized?

In .NET, it's `UserControl_Loaded`. What is VB6 version of this if any?

Comment: It says in the url I posted that " For UserControl objects, Load and Unload are superseded by the ReadProperties and WriteProperties events."

Answer (score 0):

I tend to put "load" logic into the InitProperties and ReadProperties event handlers.  The first one gets called when a UserControl instance is added to a container (Form, another UserControl) within the IDE.  The second one gets called on all subsequent "creations" within the IDE and at run time.

You can check Ambient.UserMode to determine whether a subsequent creation's ReadProperties event is due to editing operations vs. an IDE or compiled run.

Initialize events always occur, and before the other two.  At that time Ambient and other context objects are not available yet.

See that fine manual: [Understanding Control Lifetime and Key Events](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa733730(v=vs.60).aspx)